# DocuSign Download Attachment

Tags: download, attachment, docusignapi

We were told by a DocuSign representative that the 'envelopesApi.getDocument()' will give us back the document with any attachments attached to it. I am getting the document back but no attachments. The attachment is well under 5 MB (it's only a few hundred K). The document does show if the user goes and looks at the document through the DocuSign website.

The downloaded document does have a paperclip that does nothing when clicked. The attachment is not at the end of the document or under the .pdf attachments.

I need a way to get the attachment without sending the user to your website, if possible. The envelopesApi.getDocument() is not working, unless I'm somehow doing something incorrectly. Is there another way to download the attachment through the api without sending the user to the DocuSign website?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably too late, but try using "combined" as the value for documentId in this call:

```
envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeID, "combined")
```

That will give you all the signed documents with the summary info and all attachments in a single PDF.